# Cluster stuck on high heap usage

Tags: elasticsearch

I have **Elasticsearch v 2.2.0 cluster, 1 node, 4g heap size, 7g RAM, 2 cpu cores, 401 indices, 1,873 shards, 107,780,287 docs, total data 70.19GB**.

I also have configured **indices.fielddata.cache.size: 40%**.

The problem is when I am using Kibana to query some thing (very simple queries), if it a single query it`s working fine, but if I continue to query some more - elastic is getting so slow and eventually stuck because the JVM heap usage (from Marvel) is getting to 87-95%. It happens also when I trying to load some Kibana dashboard and the only solution for this situation is to restart the elastic service or [clear all cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-clearcache.html).

Why is the heap stuck like that?

**EDIT:**

[_node/stats when heap is stuck](https://gist.github.com/radap/16851dd5f7d8e5fee9ac5fffc688180d)

[_node/stats when cluster in normal state](https://gist.github.com/radap/c5a8eeadef6e97db99c9be515b9f1a2d)

**EDIT 2:**

To better understand the problem, I went as far as analyzing a memory dump. This analysis was performed after the cluster stuck trying some Kibana queries:

[image]

**Problem Suspect 1:**
[image]

**Problem Suspect 2:**
[image]

**Problem Suspect 3:**
[image]

I do have, in some indices, settings of _ttl that is NOT working (the _ttl set is for 4 weeks but the documents still there...). I have changed the default mappings since then but have not deleted the "not working ttl" indices.

Can it be the main problem?

Comment: Can you share in a gist the result of `GET /_nodes/stats`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have other choice now than to **add more nodes to your cluster, increase the hardware resources for the current node or don't store that many indices in the cluster**.

You have a lot of shards for such a small node and all those shards use some memory (767MB) for the usual things: terms, norms and overall memory used by segments' metadata:

```
    "segments": {
      "count": 14228,
      "memory_in_bytes": 804235553,
      "terms_memory_in_bytes": 747176621,
      "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 31606496,
      "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
      "norms_memory_in_bytes": 694880,
      "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 24757556,
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
      "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 1381097464,
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 39362,
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0
    }
```

You moved to ES 2.x this means you are now using doc_values by default and fielddata usage is, indeed, very small (11.8MB):

```
    "fielddata": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 12301920,
      "evictions": 0
    }
```

The old filter cache (now called query cache) is, also, very small:

```
    "query_cache": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 302888,
```

Clearing the cache (fielddata, query cache) I am not so sure it makes a big difference.  At the time the stats were gathered the heap usage was at 2.88GB (72%) which is not that high (at 75% the JVM triggers an old GC). But still, to me that is a too small node for that many shards.

One more thing to be aware of, and unrelated to the memory issue:

```
    "open_file_descriptors": 29461,
    "max_file_descriptors": 65535,
```

With so many opened file descriptors I strongly suggest to [increase the OS limit for the count of open file descriptors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#file-descriptors).

Comment: but why indices.fielddata.cache.size: 40% isn't take care of the heap resources?

Comment: also, I didn't understand why should I increase the OS limit for the count of open file descriptors? In the link you provided there is no explanation...

Comment: also, I didn't understand what is consuming the whole heap when the cluster is stuck? I guess it is not the fielddata, and I saw the query cache is 0, so what is the bottleneck?

Comment: Fielddata was "taken care of" by moving to ES 2.x where doc_values are used instead of the fielddata by default. There are some fields that still use fielddata, but your cluster's fielddata seems to be ok. Regarding file descriptors, if the system runs out of them (and implicitly ES), then ES will not be able to function anymore. Your indices are made of files on disk basically (lots of them). And ES uses file descriptors to open those files and access them.

Comment: Regarding Heap, ES uses part of it for its own things, loading classes, buffers, computing aggregations, doing sorting etc. 4GB heap is not a big value, btw. The best approach to look at the actual heap is to take a heapdump (`jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.hprof <PID>`) and use a tool like Yourkit or Eclipse MAT to look at the dump.But for me, a 4GB heap with 72% usage given that memory usage for segments, is not uncommon.

Comment: Please see my edit! I have add the dump analyzer results!

Comment: It seems it's still about how many indices/how much data you have in thsi cluster and the hardware resources not being enough. The memory usage seems to come from queries cache.